# Erro no tratamento de um retorno em JSON no AJAX

Tags: ajax, json

Já faz 3 dias que eu estou pesquisando em vários sites da rede que tratam deste assunto uma solução para o meu problema, mas não estou conseguindo descobrir a causa do mesmo.

Venho pedir uma ajuda aos experts no assunto, pois já estou ficando meio desesperado com tantas tentativas frustradas de resolver uma coisa que ao meu ver deve ser simples, mas que esta me deixando mais careca ainda.

Eu tenho tentado tratar o retorno de uma consulta feita em PHP que retorna um objeto JSON em um script que usarei em um site que estou criando, mas não consigo acessar as camadas do objeto.

Sempre vejo no console.log do Firefox o seguinte: `undefined`.

O meu código PHP é este abaixo e funciona perfeitamente executando-o isoladamente no navegador, passando o parâmetro necessário que é o `idPro=XXX`.

O código faz uma pesquisa no banco e retorna todos os produtos que atendem a solicitação.

**O retorno do código em PHP é assim:**

```
[
 {"id":"123","descricao":"PRODUTO 1"},
 {"id":"345","descricao":"PRODUTO 2"},
 {"id":"567","descricao":"PRODUTO 3"},
 {"id":"789","descricao":"PRODUTO 4"}
]
```

No código do javascript tenho tentado me referir ao objeto para pegar os dados dentro dele e mostrar apenas no console.log por enquanto, ainda não implantei o resto do código onde será realmente usado os dados, pois primeiro preciso fazer funcionar no console.log.

Eu resumi um pouco com a intenção de simplificar.

Desde já agradeço imensamente.

**Código 1:**

```js
$(document).ready(function()
{
 $("input[name='codigo']").bind("change paste keyup blur", function()
 {
  var codigodigitado   =  $('#codigo').val();
  var retorno = '';
  
  console.log( codigodigitado ); // Aqui mostra no console o que eu digitei no campo do form (funciona ok).
  
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST", 
  //dataType: 'json', //Se eu ativo isso, nada retorna.
  data: {idPro: codigodigitado}, //parâmetro de pesquisa passao ao php (funciona ok).
  url: "busca_descricao.php", 
  beforeSend: function(){
   // Funcionou (coloquei apenas para testar).
   //console.log("Isso executara antes da requisicao"); // funciona ok.
  },
  success: function(responses){
   // Funcionou (mostra corretamente os dados).
   console.log(responses); // Aqui são os dados vindos do PHP (fuciona ok).

   // O problema esta aqui: (não mostra o conteúdo do objeto)
   console.log(responses.id); // undefined (não funcionou).
   console.log(responses[0].id); // undefined (não funcionou).
   console.log(responses["0"].id); // undefined (não funcionou).
   
   
   // Isso será usado depois que eu resolver o problema acima.
   //var options = { 
   //data: responses,
   //getValue: "id"
   //};
 
   //$("#codigo").easyAutocomplete(options);    
   
  }
  });
   
  
 });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" name="codigo" id="codigo" autocomplete="off" required />
```

**Código 2:**

```html
<?php
require("user_ver_login.php");
include("include/admin.php");
include("include/conexao.php");
//
if(isset($_POST['idPro'])) {
 $idPro = $_POST["idPro"];
} elseif(isset($_GET['idPro'])) {
 $idPro = $_GET["idPro"];
} else {
 $data = array();
 $retorno = array_push ( $data ,  array( "id" => "0", "descricao" => utf8_encode( "Nada foi passado!" ) ) );
 $retorno = json_encode($data);
 echo $retorno;  
 exit;
}
//
$idUsu = $_SESSION['idUsubd']; // Pega o ID do usuário
////$sql = "SELECT Descricao,Preco FROM produto WHERE idPro='$idPro' and idUsu='$idUsu'"; // Pega só os produtos do usuário.
$sql = "SELECT idPro,Descricao FROM produto WHERE Descricao like '%$idPro%'"; // Pega todos os produtos (apenas para o teste do json).
$cont = 0;
$result = mysqli_query($conexao, $sql);
$cont = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$data = array();
////$contador = 0;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
  array_push ( $data ,  array( "id" => utf8_encode($row[0]), "descricao" => utf8_encode( trim( $row[1] ) ) ) );
  ////$contador = $contador + 1;
}
if ($cont == 0) {
 $retorno = array_push ( $data ,  array( "id" => "0", "descricao" => utf8_encode( "Produto inexistente!" ) ) );
}
// Converte para o formato json.
////header('Content-Type: application/json'); // não funcionou, dá erro!
$retorno = json_encode($data);
// Retorna o array direto sem converter (apenas um teste).
//$retorno = $data;
echo $retorno;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe diferença entre JSON e **STRING DE JSON**. Se o console anterior você exibe um JSON, mas na hora de pegar o dado dele não funciona, possivelmente ele é uma string, e precisa ser convertido para JSON usando o PARSE. No success, coloque:

```
responses = JSON.parse(responses)
```

Embora você perdeu 3 dias, não fique triste, pois também já perdi vários dias nisso, e mais de uma vez! haha E tenho certeza que outras pessoas já perderam também.

Aproveitando o tópico, já gostaria de te dar outra dica e que me ajuda muito. Sempre que for exibir um JSON no console, para ele ficar mais bonito, você pode fazer da seguinte maneira:

```
console.log('responses', JSON.stringify(responses, null, 2))
```

E se estiver usando o VSCODE, pode criar um snippet e ao digitar o prefixo **cls** e apertar TAB, já escreve esse console.log.

```
"Print to console": {
        "scope": "javascript,typescript",
        "prefix": "cls",
        "body": [
            "console.log('$1', JSON.stringify($1, null, 2))"
        ],
        "description": "Console.log com JSON.stringify"
    }
```

Comment: Olá Gleidson, obrigado pelo seu retorno.
Fiz tudo que você sugeriu mas sem nenhum sucesso.

Estou bem desconfiado que seja alguma falha no meu XAMPP.
Eu vou colocar todo o meu conteúdo em um servidor real na Web para ver se o resultado é o mesmo.

Assim que tiver alguma novidade eu posto.

Muito obrigado
:)

Comment: Por favor, poste o resultado de `console.log(responses);` do success.

Comment: Gleidson, consegui resolver. Vou postar a solução.
Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda.
:)

Answer (score 0):

Conforme eu tinha comentado anteriormente todas as minhas suspeitas se confirmaram.
Migrei todo o meu projeto para um servidor WEB e o resultado do console.log(responses); do success retornou a JSON corretamente.
Fiz vários testes e todas as tentativas válidas que antes eram frustradas passaram a funcionar como deveriam.

Então fica aqui a dica:
O XAMPP não trabalha corretamente com os retornos JSON.

Vou prosseguir com o desenvolvimento do projeto diretamente no servidor Web de agora em diante.
É uma pena, pois era muito pratico usar o XAMPP como localhost, pois não era preciso usar FTP para ficar subindo as alterações toda hora.

Sempre utilizei o XAMPP para desenvolver, fuciona muito bem com o PHP e o MySQL, uso até com o Wordpress e em projetos bem grandes. 
Mas como foi a primeira vez que utilizei jquery em um nível mais profundo, nem imaginava que isso poderia ocorrer.

Mas sei que isso é uma quiestão de tempo até resolverem.

Deixo o meu muito obrigado a todos que colaboraram.
:)

Comment: Trabalhar diretamente no servidor é extremamente ruim. E se você fizer as configurações de servidor manualmente invés de usar o XAMPP, ou então usar outro? Pode ser que funcione, pois se online funciona, provavelmente é simplesmente alguma configuração no local que não esteja certo. Mas de qualquer forma, que bom que conseguiu.

Comment: Olá Gleidson, instalei hoje o WAMP e configurei todos os meus aliases e pastas. 
Nele funciona tudo normalmente e agora posso continuar o trabalho que já ficou meio atrasado. 

Te agradeço pela força. Valeu mesmo! 

Quando eu tiver um tempo irei analisar o XAMPP com mais calma pra ver se descubro o problema, mas tem um monte de gente na rede que já passou por algo semelhante. Mas sem nenhuma solução.

Abraços. ;)

Comment: Opa, fico feliz que deu certo! =]